# Watson Knowledge studio, dictionary updation is not reflected in the current task

Tags: watson-knowledge-studio

How to update dictionary in Watson Knowledge Studio and apply changes into the current task when already started human annotation.
I updated the dictionary(i.e. added few keywords required) and applied pre-annotation. The changes in dictionary were not updated in the annotation set in current task. Is there a way we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply dictionary update to existing tasks.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio/annotate-documents.html#wks_hatask

You may be interested in the concordance tool to label multiple occurrences of a mention at once.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio/user-guide.html#wks_haentity